# AdMob stop showing banner after removing the mediation - Android

Tags: android, admob, mobile-ad-mediation

I had Smart Banner and normal banner in my app.
they were working normally, i tried to add mediation with AdColony, i made all the good integration.
After the AdColony Network was always pending optimazation, I decided to remove the mediation.

when the mediation was removed and now the AdMob (default) is only present.
The Banners stopped showing any ads.

what could went wrong??